# How to write universal optimistic concurrency Timestamp column that works with SQL Server and with Postgresql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We need to support both databases: SQL Server and Postgresql. For optimistic concurrency we use a `[Timestamp]` column.

For SQL Server this code works:

```
public class DbEntity
{
    ...
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In the database, this field is mapped to:

```
[Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
```

For Postgresql we need something like this:

```
public class DbEntity
{
    ...
    [Timestamp]
    public uint Version { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

without column in database, because xmin system column used - https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/concurrency.html?tabs=data-annotations

It is possible to write universal entities that works with both databases? I want to write them once, and do not support 2 applications or 2 branches in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use have both properties on your .NET type and vary the EF model configuration based on the provider being used, and ignore the property for the other databases:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public uint Version { get; set; }
}

// In the model configuration:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (Database.IsSqlServer())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Ignore(b => b.Version);
    }
    else if (Database.IsNpgsql())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Ignore(b => b.Timestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to make with only one property `byte[] Timestamp`. In this case additionally `Conversion` must be configured: https://github.com/alex-t0/EntityFrameworkCoreConcurrencyTokens/blob/single-field/WebApp/Db/AwesomeDbContext.cs.